# Изменение элементов происходит только после выполнения другого действия

Tags: java, swing

```
tf.username.setEnabled(false);
tf.password.setEnabled(false);
tf.cb.setEnabled(false);
tf.button.setEnabled(false);
tf.imageLabel.setVisible(true);

Parser pars=new Parser(user, password);
String[] answer=pars.getData();
```

`tf` - это `JPanel`. В `Parser` происходит отправка *GET* и *POST* запросов с помощью *Apache HttpClient* и затем работа с *Excel* через *Apache Poi*.

Проблема в том, что изменение на панели происходят только после окончания работы метода `getData()`.

Comment: Вы про изменения, что выше `Parser` или после него?

Comment: Тот код, что выше.

Comment: Не, это не то. Действительно так, что графика происходит в одном потоке с `getData()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас выполнение `getData()` происходит в том же потоке, в котором происходит отрисовка GUI. Вынесите в отдельный поток и всё станет норм, для более подробного понимания читайте офф. [доку про потоки в Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) и особое внимание на [EDT(The Event Dispatch Thread).](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Т.е. в ваше случае должно быть что-то такое:

```
tf.username.setEnabled(false);
tf.password.setEnabled(false);
tf.cb.setEnabled(false);
tf.button.setEnabled(false);
tf.imageLabel.setVisible(true);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Parser pars=new Parser(user, password);
        String[] answer=pars.getData();
        // Все остальные действия с результатом
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Вы имеете в виду `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`? Пробовал, та же ситуация.

Comment: @Vladius001 я имею в виду, что выполнять тяжелые действия, типа запроса на сервер, надо в отдельном потоке. А не в EDT.

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое. Я не в ту сторону пробовал.